# Inserting data are not displaying in Phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

i am making a text entry based form name phone address using mysql with php connection is working but when i enter data through address bar then data are not showing in my database table in phpmyadmin
    here is my code

```
<?php
     $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST";
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
   // $db_selected = mysql_select_db("MyTest",$con);
     mysqli_select_db($con, "MyTest");
    error_reporting(0);

    // url link http://localhost/test/index.php?name=&phone=&address=

    //http://localhost/test/index.php?name=qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq&phone=1111&address=asasasasaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa


    $Name =   ($_REQUEST["Name"]);
    $Phone =  ($_REQUEST["Phone"]);
    $Address = ($_REQUEST["Address"]);
    //($_POST ["name"]);
    $qur="INSERT INTO Details(Name,Phone,Address)values('Rajat','1234','Noida')";

        if($qur){
            echo "Testing";
        $json = array("1");
           // echo "(qur)";
    // $data="Select * from Details";
    }else{
        $json = array("0");
        echo "My first PHP script not working!";
       // echo no data available

    }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($json);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending your query $qur to the server. See for example https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/func_mysqli_query.asp.